# how to bring edit text in front when it has focus or is selected in android

Tags: android, select, focus, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have 3 edit texts on a screen. On small screen devices before touching a edittext my screen looks like

[image]

And after touching first edittext(e.g. in front of name), keyboard popup comes, and it looks

[image]

i.e. now edittext Amount(which in front of TextView named Amount) is now in front of the user. But as I have touched(or clicked) first(Name) edittext, I want it in front of the user. But no matter which I select every time Amount is in front.

I have tried using requestFocus() and setSelect(true). Even has focus returns true, but nothing works.

So how to do that?

I have given scroll view to the tablelayout which contains these three edittexts and three text boxes in front of them.

my xml code is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_upload_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/selected_image_detail"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_upload_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/name_table" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_img_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/text_box_background"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/name"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/amount_table" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/text_box_background"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/amount"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/desc_table" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/text_box_background"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint="@string/desc"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_upload_bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="70dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_update"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_update" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below line to manifest for related activity,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```